# display rows/cells in UITableview one by one with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, animation

I have a table view with a prototype cell designed in ViewController scene of storyboard.

Now my objective is when the app will start and the view will be loaded then the data in tableview should not come at once rather it will come one by one with animation.

**Here is the code how I am doing my animation:-**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (![shownIndexes containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [shownIndexes addObject:indexPath];
       [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f delay:0.0f usingSpringWithDamping:0.5f initialSpringVelocity:1.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent animations:^{
            vw.frame = frame;
      } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

      }];
  }
```

**Other methods:-**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    return 1;    //count of section
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 20;    //count number of row from counting array hear cataGorry is An Array
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 120;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"CellA";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
 return cell;


}
```

The following code is animating the first 5 cells which are displaying in tableview initially at once   , but after that when I am scrolling it is happening one by one.

**So major issue is**

How to display the rows or cells in UITableview one by one with animation not at once?

Any info or help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the question? may be make it more clearer

Comment: How to display the rows or cells in UITableview one by one with animation not at once? @omerio

Comment: You can increment delay on the i animation, e.g. 2 second on the second cell, 4 seconds on the third etc., but as you can see it will take forever, so make sure your users won't pass away before your animation ends.

Comment: Did you find a proper answer ?

Answer (score -1):

Tell the table first that in only has one row, in `numberOfRows…`. After a delay, return 2 instead of 1. And so on.

Comment: Is that really a solution! How you expect this will work, How you can suppose to give a delay in 'numberOfRows' , it means you have to call reload table view, which will surely animate again the previous cell.

Comment: You can use insert `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` also.

Comment: You can alter the number of rows without reloading the whole table. What sunshine proposes is one way, also check `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`.